# newline or line breaks in rnotebook inline chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

How to make newlines in inline chunks ? Rendering a word document

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: word_document
---

Cat `r cat("not \n working")`

writeLines `r writeLines("not \n working")`

print `r print("not \n working")`

capture.output + cat `r capture.output(cat("not \n working"))`

```{r results='asis'}
cat("not \n working")
```
````

**EDIT Solution based on shafee and gaut's answers uses triple escape character** `\`

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: word_document
---

Text `r "Simple \\\n is \\\n better"`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use:

````
```{r results='asis'}

cat(paste("it is", "\\\n", "working"))

```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I chose an even simpler way based on your answer : `r "it is\\\nworking"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `combine_words` from `{knitr}` to do this in inline code.

```
`r knitr::combine_words(c("it is", "working"), sep = "\\\n", and = "")`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I chose an even simpler way based on your answer : `r "it is\\\nworking"`. Would there be an advantage of using `combine_words()` instead ?

Comment: For your case?! I don't think so!

Comment: Ok thanks ! do you know a way to make hard returns instead of soft returns when rendering a word document ?